# How could I graph z=sqrt(x^2-y^2) using Pgftools? I believe I've all suggestions on the internet but to no avail

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I have tried graphing it with the parametric notation (i.e. ({x},{y},{sort(x^2-y^2)}) and as seen on my code below but nothing renders the image shown on graphing calculators.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
grid=major,
3d box=complete,
enlargelimits=false,
colormap/cool,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$z$,
zlabel style = {sloped like x axis}
]
\addplot3 [
surf,
shader=faceted,
samples=50,
z buffer=sort,
]  {sqrt((x)^2-(y)^2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did almost everything right, `pgfplots` is just not very good at taking the square root of a negative number. So if you adjust the domains a bit you get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
grid=major,
3d box=complete,
enlargelimits=false,
colormap/cool,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$z$,
zlabel style = {sloped like x axis}
]
\addplot3 [domain=2:4,domain y=-2:2,
surf,
shader=faceted,
samples=50,
z buffer=sort,
]  {sqrt(x^2-y^2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your request in the comments, one can write the function as `sqrt(u*v)`, where `u=x+y` and `v=x-y`. Then `x=(u+v)/2` and `y=(u-v)/2`. Since the variables are just placeholders in a parametric plot, we can rename `u` and `v` to `x` and `y`, respectively, and arrive at

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[xmax=2,xmin=-2,
grid=major,
3d box=complete,
enlargelimits=false,
colormap/cool,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$z$,
zlabel style = {sloped like x axis}
]
\addplot3 [domain=0:4,domain y=0:4,
surf,
shader=faceted,
samples=50,
z buffer=sort,
] ({(x+y)/2},{(x-y)/2},{sqrt(x*y)});
\addplot3 [domain=0:4,domain y=0:4,
surf,
shader=faceted,
samples=50,
z buffer=sort,
] ({-(x+y)/2},{-(x-y)/2},{sqrt(x*y)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks though that fixed most of it. Though yesterday I forgot to post the image of how I would like my graph to look like. How can I make the graph look more [like this?](https://imgur.com/a/coi64oJ)

Comment: @DanielHernández I added a graph of this sort.

Comment: ©marmot Thanks! That's what I needed. Pgfplots still is kind of confusing for me.

Comment: @DanielHernández You are welcome! (The issue here is more a parametrization question than a pgfplots question, I think. But you're right, pgfplots is a nontrivial packages with lots of functionality that one keeps discovering.)